# How do I compile libgit2 for Android

Tags: cmake, android-ndk, clang, clang++, libgit2

recently I've been working on a flutter app, which uses libgit2 and I had no issues compiling the libgit2 repo for linux. Now, I would like to add support for android, so I tried to compile it using the Android NDK (r26) and the following `toolchain.cmake`:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 34)

set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI arm64-v8a)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK /opt/android-ndk)

set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR "/path/to/openssl/include")
set(OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY "/path/to/openssl/libcrypto.so")
set(OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY "/path/to/openssl/libssl.so")
```

*with the acutual path to the openssl repo instead of `/path/to/openssl`.*

I had no problem compiling openssl with the NDK. However, compiling libgit2, which uses cmake instead of `./Config`, gave me this error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/opt/android-ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.
```

The file `/opt/android-ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang` is aparently a text file with the name of the acutal clang binary `clang-17`. I have little experience with cmake and none with the NDK, but I tried to add this to the toolchain file, which didn't do anything:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   /opt/android-ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang-17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /opt/android-ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang-17)
```

I even tried to replace the text files with symlinks, which also didn't work, but gave a different error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/opt/android-ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: '/home/jakub/Projekty/dpc/lib/libgit/build/arm64/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-03LVGf'
    
    Run Build Command(s): /usr/bin/cmake -E env VERBOSE=1 /usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_f226c/fast
    /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_f226c.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_f226c.dir/build
    gmake[1]: Vstupuje se do adresáře „/media/data/Všechny Projekty/dpc/lib/libgit/build/arm64/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-03LVGf“
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_f226c.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    /opt/android-ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang --target=aarch64-none-linux-android34   -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fexceptions  -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -MD -MT CMakeFiles/cmTC_f226c.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/cmTC_f226c.dir/testCCompiler.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_f226c.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /home/jakub/Projekty/dpc/lib/libgit/build/arm64/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-03LVGf/testCCompiler.c
    Linking C executable cmTC_f226c
    /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_f226c.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /opt/android-ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang --target=aarch64-none-linux-android34 -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fexceptions  -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-undefined-version -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--gc-sections -Qunused-arguments -Wl,--no-undefined  -Wl,--gc-sections  CMakeFiles/cmTC_f226c.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_f226c   -latomic -lm 
    clang: error: unable to execute command: posix_spawn failed: Exec format error
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Output of `/opt/android-ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang --version` is:

```
Android (10087095, +pgo, +bolt, +lto, -mlgo, based on r487747c) clang version 17.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project d9f89f4d16663d5012e5c09495f3b30ece3d2362)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/android-ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin
```

I also tried using different NDK versions and with `r22b` (or older) it configured itself and almost compiled, where the clang version was `11.0.5`. Then, it had problems with it's own header files, not recognising the `inline` keyword:

```
/opt/android-ndk-r22/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/linux/swab.h:40:8: error: unknown type name 'inline'
static inline __attribute__((__const__)) __u32 __fswahw32(__u32 val) {
       ^
/opt/android-ndk-r22/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/linux/swab.h:40:47: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
static inline __attribute__((__const__)) __u32 __fswahw32(__u32 val) {
```

Thank you so much in advance for any help.

Comment: "I even tried to replace the text files with symlinks" - Changing toolchain files is what normally should be avoided. Your settings of variable `CMAKE_C_COMPILER ` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` in the toolchain file should work. Just cleanup the previous configuration (e.g. by deleting `CMakeCache.txt` file from the **build** directory).

Comment: I have the same error